# How can you base a Joi `when` condition on a value from the context?

Tags: validation, joi

Joi's [ref documentation](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.2.1#refkey-options) suggests that a Reference created using `Joi.ref` can refer to a value from the context object. Joi's [any.when documentation](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.2.1#anywhencondition-options) suggests that the `condition` parameter accepts a Reference. However, I can't get the following simple usage to work:

```js
import Joi from "joi";

const schema = Joi.object({
  year: Joi.number().when(Joi.ref(`$flag`), {
    is: Joi.boolean().truthy,
    then: Joi.number().min(2000),
  }),
});

const value = {
  year: 1999,
};

const context = {
  flag: true
};

const result = schema.validate(value, { context });
```

This code results in a passing validation. However, I would expect it to fail. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `boolean().valid(true)` so only the boolean value `true` passes!

`boolean().truthy()` accepts a list of **additional** values to be considered valid booleans. E.g. `boolean().truthy('YES', 'Y')`. Details in the [Documentation](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#booleantruthyvalues)

`joi` version: **17.2.1**

```js
const Joi = require('joi');

const schema = Joi.object({
  year: Joi.number().when(
    Joi.ref('$flag'), {
      is: Joi.boolean().valid(true), then: Joi.number().min(2000),
    },
  ),
});

const value = {
  year: 1999,
};

// fails
const context = {
  flag: true
};

// passes
const context = {
  flag: false
};

const result = schema.validate(value, { context });
console.log(result.error);
```

Comment: No problem :) Intuitively I would use `truthy` too. `valid(true)` is not the most straight-forward API I've seen

Comment: Instead of using `is: Joi.boolean().valid(true)` you can just use `is: true` and it will work.